# Are wine-based and mono-based programs started differently?

Tags: gnome, wine, mono

I was wondering if wine-based and mono-based programs are started differently?

1. For wine-based, I go through Gnome GUI, clicking Applications ->
   Wine -> Programs -> . How can I call it from terminal?
2. For mono-based, I use terminal, where I type `mono path-to-program`.
   Can I call it from Gnome GUI?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wine: In terminal: `wine /path/to/executable.exe`

Mono: create a shortcut or a launcher, and have it as `mono /path/to/program.exe`   (another method is to hit Alt+F2 and type in `mono /path/to/program.exe`)

That should answer your two questions.